# magento admin login starnge issue , twice login to login

Tags: magento-1.9

i have strange issue with my admin login , i have to login twice then i am able to login , for first time it says password error next time i am able to login ,

```
1: url is same like abcd.com/admin 
2: what could be issue how to fix it please guide me way to fix it 
3: i had checked some previous answer my both url are same means non-www
4: magento version 1.9.0.1
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you have any 3rd party code to do with changing the admin login controller? Does the same thing happen when users login?

Comment: have you tried with a fresh incognito window to check if it is an issue relating to session cookies?